# Using GuzzleHttp Client to read a text document from drive

Tags: symfony, google-drive-api, guzzle

I am trying to write a command which will read a text file uploaded on google drive using its sharable link.I am using symfony2.
This is my code.

```
         use GuzzleHttp\Client;
         use GuzzleHttp\Exception\RequestException;


         $queryFile = 'https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B6NZHCoBtjaLZXRmWG5JQWhLWEU'
         try {
                $client =  new Client();
                $cloudFile = "temp/query";
                $request = $client->get($queryFile, ['save_to'=>$cloudFile]);
                $fileName = $cloudFile;
                $file = fopen($fileName, 'r');
                $queryStatement = fread($file, filesize($fileName));
                $output->writeln($queryStatement);
                if (!$file) {
                    $output->writeln('<error> Cannot open the file </error>');

                    return;
                }
            } catch (RequestException $e) {
                $output->writeln('Fetching cloud file failed');
            }
```

And the sharable link is

```
https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B6NZHCoBtjaLZXRmWG5JQWhLWEU
```

But this is the result I got.

```
<!DOCTYPE html><html><head><meta name="google" content="notranslate"><meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge;"><meta name="fragment" content="!"><title>query - Google Drive</title><meta property="og:title" content="query"><meta property="og:type" content="article"><meta property="og:site_name" content="Google Docs"><meta property="og:url" content="https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B6NZHCoBtjaLZXRmWG5JQWhLWEU/view?usp=sharing&amp;usp=embed_facebook"><meta name="twitter:card" content="photo"><meta name="twitter:title" content="query"><meta name="twitter:url" content="https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B6NZHCoBtjaLZXRmWG5JQWhLWEU/view?usp=sharing&amp;usp=embed_twitter"><meta name="twitter:site" content="@googledocs"><script>(function(){(function(){function e(a){this.t={};this.tick=function(a,c,b){var d=void 0!=b?b:(new Date).getTime();this.t[a]=[d,c];if(void 0==b)try{window.console.timeStamp("CSI/"+a)}catch(e){}};this.tick("start",null,a)}var a;window.performance&&(a=window.performance.timing);var f=a?new e(a.responseStart):new e;window.jstiming={Timer:e,load:f};if(a){var c=a.navigationStart,d=a.responseStart;0<c&&d>=c&&(window.jstiming.srt=d-c)}if(a){var b=window.jstiming.load;0<c&&d>=c&&(b.tick("_wtsrt",void 0,c),b.tick("wtsrt_",
```

Comment: which version of guzzle are you using? Check the allow redirect options as described in the doc here https://github.com/guzzle/guzzle/blob/master/docs/request-options.rst#allow_redirects

Comment: I am using guzzle5 which allows to save this way. http://guzzle3.readthedocs.org/http-client/request.html#creating-requests-with-a-client

Comment: from the doc you posted seem you miss the statement:  `$response = $request->send();`